# What's time complexity of this algorithm for finding all combinations?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o, combinations

> **Combinations** 
>   Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers out of 1 ... n.
>   **For example**, If n = 4 and k = 2, a solution is:
>
> ```
> [
>    [2, 4],
>    [3, 4],
>    [2, 3],
>    [1, 2],
>    [1, 3],
>    [1, 4],
> ]
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Personally I think**,
>  time complexity = O(n^k), n and k are input.
>
> ---
>
> **Thank you for all help.**
>   **Finally**, the time complexity = O(C(n,k) * k) = O((n!/(k! * (n - k)!)) * k),
>   n and k is input,
>   Since, each time when we get a combination, we need copy subList list to one_rest, which is O(k),
>   there is C(n, k) * k.
>
> ---
>
> **C++**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int> > combine(int n, int k) {
        vector<vector<int>> list;

        // Input validation.
        if (n < k) return list;

        int start = 1;
        vector<int> subList;
        helper(n, k, start, list, subList);

        return list;
    }

    void helper(int n, int k, int start, 
                vector<vector<int>> &list, vector<int> &subList) {
        // Base case.
        if (subList.size() == k) {
            vector<int> one_rest(subList);
            list.push_back(one_rest);
            return;
        }
        if (start > n) return;

        for (int i = start; i <= n; i ++) {
            // Have a try.
            subList.push_back(i);

            // Do recursion.
            helper(n, k, i + 1, list, subList);

            // Roll back.
            subList.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using lists, `push_back` and `pop_back` are `O(1)` operations. Also, you end up generating a valid combination exactly once. Thus, the complexity is `O(n choose k)`.

Comment: Can you write complexities in terms of combination such as O(n choose k), or do you have to provide the final equivalence. Could you point me to reference on this.

Comment: `f(x) = O(g(x))` is a rigorous statement about the limiting behaviour of `f(x)` and `g(x)`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). There is nothing wrong in saying `O(n choose k)`. However, depending on your situation, you might want a different looking `g(x)`. For example, if you are trying to compare a `O(n choose k)` algorithm with some other exponential complexity algo, you might want to replace `n choose k` with something that uses [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas).

Answer (score 29):

The complexity is `O(C(n,k))` which is `O(n choose k)`.

This ends up being equivalent to `O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))`.

Comment: How it could be O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))?

Comment: Let `n=11` and `k=8`, `n-k = 3` then `11 choose 8 = 165` and `11 choose 3 = 165`. You'll find that `n choose k` for `k <= n / 2` is `O(N^k)`. While for `k > n / 2`, the formula is `O(n^(n-k))`. You could write this as piecewise function, basically how I just described it there, or you can simply say `O(min(n^k, n^(n-k))`. This becomes clearer if you look at the formulas for how to calculate `n choose k` for specific values of `k`.

Comment: While it's true that C(n,k) is an element of O(n^k), this is a very loose upper bound if k is large; for instance, [C(n, n/2) < 2^n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Approximations) << n^(n/2) = sqrt(n)^n.

Comment: @Stef That's I had `min` in there. You use the smaller of `O(n^k)` and `O(n^(n-k))`. if `k >> n/2` then `O(n^(n-k))` is very small and is the one that should be used instead. There's probably a way to re-write it that doesn't require the `min()`, but even now can't think of one.

Comment: @Nuclearman I should have said "if k is close to n/2" rather than "if k is large". I'm well aware that C(n, k) = C(n, n-k). That's not what I am criticising. What I am saying is that n^k is a very loose bound, unless k is very close to 0 or to n. The extreme case is k = n/2: in that case, C(n, k) is less than 2^n, but n^k = sqrt(n)^n is much larger than 2^n.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean now. Fair enough, it is mostly useful for when k is small compared to `N`. It does end up closer to `O(N^N)` rather than `O(2^N)` as `k` approaches `n/2`. So I would agree it becomes rather loose indeed as `k` approaches `n/2`.

Answer (score 5):

The time complexity is equal to the number of combinations there are.

In this case it is `n choose k`.

Comment: +1, the simple and obvious answer, since the algorithm will have to generate **all** combinations and these (for given n, k) are known to be $n choose k$ this is also the time complexity of the algorithm (else the algorithm will produce biased combinations, either some missing or duplicates)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is O(n^k). Because think about it. Let's assume n=100 and k=2. According to your complexity it will 100 to the power 2. But if it is n=100 and k=10, it will be 100 to the power of 10. But if you think about it, there are far more combinations with n=100,k=2 than n=100,k=10. The complexity is actually is the actual formula: which is n!/(k!*(n-k)!). And the complexity therefore will be O(n!/k!*(n-k)!).

Comment: That is not necessary a contradiction. Big-O notation specifies the upper bound and as such specific numeric examples are less applicable to it. `n!/k!(n-k)!` is the actual exact computation and as such can serve as the tightest boundary for complexity. However, the answer depends on the problem definition. If both `k` and `n` are variables, then the complexity is `O(n!/k!(n-k)!)`. But if `k` is constant - `n!/k!(n-k)!=O(n!/k!(n-k)!)=O(n^k)`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more about how you obtained  O(n^k) through the fact K is constant? I could not follow you.

Comment: @vinicius.olifer Replying to an old comment here, but might be useful to those in the future. `O(n!/k!(n-k)!)` is the most accurate definition, but isn't terribly useful in most situations when discussing Big O notation. The factorials just add complexity that isn't often needed. For more practical purposes, my answer above uses `O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))`. Since O just means "is not worst than", it's fine to use the higher of those two and just use O(n^k), though if `k >= n/2` it is more accurate to say `O(n^(n-k))`.