# What is the asymptotic running time of a combination?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the recurrence relation T(n, k) = T(n - 1, k - 1) + T(n - 2, k - 1) + ... + T(k + 1, k - 1).  This is the summation of T(n - i, k - 1) from i = 1 to i = n - k + 1.  Calculating the result of this by hand, I noticed that this forms pascal's triangle - T(n, k) is then (n - 1) choose (k - 1).

How would I express this as an asymptotic running time in big O notation?  I can prove that T(n, k) is O(n!), but that doesn't really show the whole picture - what if n is large, but k is just as large?  If n = k, then then running time is just 1.

Comment: In big O notation, one variable of (n,k) tends to infinity and the other one is fixed. Which is which?

Comment: @n.m. It's technically both, since both n and k are parameters of the algorithm.  k is bounded by n (k can't be any bigger than n), but as n gets large k can get large too.

Comment: The big O notation is defined for functions of one variable as that varianle tends to infinity. You can develop your own brand of Big O but you need to clearly define what the notation like O(f(x,y)) means.

Comment: @n.m. I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations - which technically makes this question a duplicate - but the answers there are using O(f(x, y)) as you say.

Comment: There's more than one possible generalization of big-O notation for multiple variables. None is commonly accepted. [One is described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables).  More are [here](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf). The last article says it is only have sense to define big-O for multiple variables when the function under big-O is strictly non-decreasing, which choose(n,k) is not, and even then one needs to use some non-trivial definitions to get the notion of big-O consistent.

Comment: @n.m. I guess it depends on the context.  This is part of a class I'm taking, and some homeworks have had big O of multiple variables as the answer.  While it might not be technically correct, it's probably what the teacher is looking for.

Comment: Can't argue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Pascal's triangle as a matrix, and you want to find the complexity of building that matrix up to size `n x k`, then the big-oh of that will be `O(n*k)`. Obviously you can't get better than that, because that's the size of the matrix.

How do we get that? Use the following simplified recurrence for combinations:

```
C(n, k) = C(n - 1, k) + C(n - 1, k - 1)
```

Computing just a single combination has the same complexity (if using memoization).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not generating the triangle - I'm saying T(n, k) is equal to the entry on the triangle.

Comment: @NmdMystery the value of `T(n, k)` is then `O((n - 1) choose (k - 1))`.

Comment: Alright, I was mostly confused about using multiple variables.  Thanks!