# Time Complexity for iterating over symmetric matrix (or n-dimensional arrays)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am curious about the **time-complexity** for iterating over a **symmetric matrix**.

I know that for standard Matrices (2-dimensional arrays), **the complexity is O(Nˆ2)**. However, for symmetric matrices, we only iterate **over the upper triangular part of it** and not over all of its elements.

This is a common algorithm for iterating over a symmetric Matrix:

```
for(int i=0; i < symmetricM.length; i++) 
        for(int j=i; j < symmetricM.length; j++ )
            System.out.println("Elem: "+symmetricM[i][j]);
```

I would like, if possible, to expand the same reasoning for any symmetric multi-dimensional arrays.

I could not calculate that by my self, but since many problems are solved with this approach,I would like to be comfortable with it in terms of complexity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the amount of elements we iterate over in a symmetric 2 dimensional array, it's `n^2/2` since the size is `n` and there are `2` dimensions so we raise to the power of 2 and divide by 2 to get only half of the elements. So `O(n^2)`.

Now let's look at the amount of elements we iterate over in a symmetric 3 dimensional array. It's `n^3/6`. You can conclude that in the same way you calculate the [volume of a 3 dimensional triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperpyramid), since all of the numbers are at this triangular area. Even after we divided by 3 the time complexity is `O(n^3)`.

For 4 dimensional it will be `n^4/(4*3*2)` which is `O(n^4)`. But for `m` dimensions it will be `n^m/m!` and since the dimension is a parameter now the time complexity will be `O(n^m/m!)` according to this method.

Another method of calculation is noticing that if you remove the diagonal of this dimension the indexes of the items you are iterating upon is the same as the combinations if you have no repeating elements and all of the elements are different. We know the amount of combinations for that is `n!/m!(n-m)!` or `n choose m` so this is can also be the time complexity.

According to most [factorial approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) the greatest element is `n^n` so when putting these approximations into use and ignoring relatively small factors, the time complexity remains the same, since:
`n!/m!(n-m)! ≈ n^n/m!(n-m)^(n-m) > n^n/m!n^(n-m) = n^m/m!`.

So eventually the time complexity will be `O(n^m/m!)`.

Comment: That's interesting analysis. Considering  2 dimensional array, that is close, but not 100% yet. It is not completely half of elements because we're including elements from the diagonal. For example, if we choose N=6, it will iterate 21 times and not 18 as the result of (nˆ2/2). But for big O analysis I believe we can ignore those few additional elements and really consider (nˆ2/2) --> O(nˆ2). Do you agree?

Comment: I also realized that if we ignore elements from the diagonal: i=0; j=i+1
Then we have a classic example of combination. For example, if we have a 4-dimensional array, we would be combining N-elements 4 to 4 OR N choose 4. We could use combination formula for that matter: N!/P!(N-P!), being P the dimension of the array. So if we have: O(N!/P!(N-P!)), is it possible to simplify that anyways?

Comment: You are correct it is not perfect since i didn't include the items in the diagonal but in big O notation it is ok. I don't understand your second comment about the combinations, can you please explain it again? Combinations of what elements?

Comment: I was referring to the formal topic of Combination in Math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination
If you iterate over your K-dimensional array of N elements, always ignoring diagonal elements (i.e. i=0 then j=i+1 then k=j+i and so on) you would actually be combining N elements in groups of K size and the order of selection does not matter. That fits the definition from that link above. I only concluded that after coding three nested FOR and printing (i + " " + j + " " + k) for each iteration.

Comment: It is similar to what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations

Comment: Your last few paragraphs are not well-founded, because [there's no standard definition of "symmetric" for higher-order matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197934/3-dimensional-array).

Comment: Oh ok I understand. Well factorial have many approximations which for most of them the largest element is `n^n` (for `n!`) so you can use these approximations and get to the result I have presented. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @ruakh you are correct, but I just followed the code example of the author and concluded his definition for that.