# What is the time complexity of `math.comb()` in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb

This is a nice convenient function for solving n choose k problems, without having to build from scratch. Does anyone know the time complexity of this specific method? Is it `O(n choose k)` as described in this question?

[What's time complexity of this algorithm for finding all combinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations/24649509)

Is there any optimization involved in the implementation of `math.comb()` that reduces the time complexity to less than `O(n choose k)`?

Comment: Here's the C code for reference:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5208b4b37953a406db0ed6a9db545c2948dde989/Modules/mathmodule.c#L3246

Comment: Producing all combinations and counting combinations are completely different problems. Producing all combinations is much more expensive.

Comment: Calculating the size of a thing doesn't require building it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is 2N, if you look at the manual code of nCr then you'll notice
One while loop for factorial(n),
one for factorial (r) and
one more for factorial (n-r).

So the while loops for calculating factorials of r and n-r are equivalent to factorial (n).

So basically it is running 2N times but, if you modify the code to store the fact(r) and fact(n-r) in a single loop while finding fact(n).
Then maybe it can be O(N).

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a definitive answer, but `math.comb()` seems to be on the slow side:

[image]

Was using `math.comb()` to solve a Pascal Triangle [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle-ii/):

```
from math import comb

def get_row(k):
    row = [None for _ in range(k+1)]
    row[0], row[-1] = 1, 1
    for y in range(1, k):
        row[y] = comb(k, y)
    return row
```

Comment: This isn't `math.comb` being slow. This is `math.comb` being applied to a task where direct computation of n choose k is an inefficient option.