# What is the order of complexity of the algorithm developed taking the x-axis as the size of the vector? (Code provided)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, code-complexity

Hi guys I am practicing my algorithm and complexity theory. I want to know what is the order of complexity of the algorithm developed taking the x-axis as the size of the vector? (Big O notation). This is the piece of code that I took and [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) and just modify a little bit

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class BigOExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] arr = {12,24,31,43,55,61};
        combinations2(arr, 4, 0, new Integer[4]);
    }

    static void combinations2(Integer[] arr, int len, int startPosition, Integer[] result){
        if (len == 0){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            return;
        }       
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
            result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
            combinations2(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
        }
    }       
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please see the following in StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations#:~:text=The%20complexity%20is%20O(C,%2C%20n%5E(n%2Dk)))%20.

Comment: The good news is, your algorithm is not inefficient, so its complexity is proportional to the length of its output. But the output is actually quite long (because there are a lot of combinations, especially if n is large and k is close to n/2)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now after a look to @MarkLavin I would say this is more like n!/k!(n-k)! (with k = 4, in this case) what do you think ?

Comment: That makes sense.