# O(n choose r) is subexponential or exponential in worth case?

Tags: complexity-theory

I try to undertstand `O(n choose r)`.
t's not that but if it for example linear, quadratic, cubic etc...

Can you tell me in what familly of complexity is `O(n choose r)` ?
Edit1:
I search to find the class of python itertools.combinations.

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Edit2:
After thinking I think it is in factorial class because in approx number of operation :

```
(n,r)
(5, 3) = 68
(6, 3) = 124
(5,4) = 49
```

and `2^5 = 32` and `2^6 = 64`

Edit3:
So not in factorial in fact `6! = 720` so not possible, I think it is max `2^n` because it is the number of possibilities possible.

Edit4:
`O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))` = in worth case `O(n^k)` so it's polynomial ? No, because K is not a constant.

Edit5:
So it's subexponential time ? I think if complexity is `O(n^k)` than :

```
(n, k)
(6, 3)
```

can be done in 216 operation, if i make `2^n` so `2^6` I get `64` sot the complexity for this problem is `216/64 = 3.375`, `3.375 * 2 ^ n` is the complexity problem ? So i get bet reduction `27 * 2^(n-3)`, so I can do cubic root and 6th root on number and get an integer so the formula is `O((n^(1/6))n^(1/3))` so it's sub_exp in the best case, but in the worth ?.

Edit6:
if I take:

```
(n,k)
(6,6)
```

so

```
6^6=46,656
2^6=64
46,656 / 64 = 729
```

So, `729 * 2^6 == 729 * 2^n`, we remove the coefficent, we have an exponential time in worth case, it's good, I have try to pass the `O((n^(1/6))^(1/3))` formula and I get also an integer.

An integer in this calculus signify is correct or not ?

Edit7:
No, sorry, i get a decimal in edit6 case, so it's more than `O((n^(1/6))^(1/3))` but how calcul that ?

Edit8:
I find, derivative, `f(x) = exp(x)` and `f'(x) = exp(x)`, i find the first derivative, `729 * 2^(n)*ln(2)` so 2^(n), so in exponential, somebody can confirm please ?

Comment: Have you familiarised yourself with the formula for "n choose r"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: i thnik it is max in O(2^n) but can lower this bound ?

Comment: If you edit your question and tell us how you arrived at that conclusion (show effort), more people are likely to put in the time to help you here.

Comment: I have no real answer because I don't understand the "choose" :/

Comment: After thinking I think it is in factorial class because in approx number of operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's time complexity of this algorithm for finding all combinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations)

Comment: This is better. Unfortunately, a tighter complexity of n choose r is slightly more complicated to express. Also keep in mind it is a function of two variables, you you cannot expect to describe its complexity class with a function of of one variable. Luckily for you, someone has already asked this question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643367/whats-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-finding-all-combinations

Comment: So O(min(n^k, n^(n-k))) = in worth case O(n^k) so is polynomial ?

Comment: LordPattern is *k* a constant i your case? If not, *O(n^k)* is not polynomial.

Comment: So it's can't be more than exp and is not polynomial, quasi polynomial, so it's subexponential time ?